# Merge two PDF pages into new one without blank spaces between text content

Tags: pdf, merge

all

I want to merge two PDFs as one PDF. In the meantime I would like to join these two PDFs seamlessly.

For example, say the last page of the first PDF file have quite a lot of empty spaces, after merging, I would hope that the second PDF will start from the blank spaces of the first PDF.

Do we have any tool supporting that?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Your request implies reflowing of PDF page material. This is not trivial, especially if headers and footers, links, etc. shall be supported. Thus, I doubt you'll find a good tool for your task, especially if you want it to be inexpensive.

Comment: +1 for mkl; You'd have to specify how much whitespace you'd still want to keep and if you want to keep the whitespace at the beginning of the 2nd doc or not. If you just want to merge you can merge with QPDF or PDFTK. In case you want to crop the first PDF and then merge you could use a Perl tool call pdfcrop.pl and then use one of the other two tools i mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

this is a not so hard task to do:

assuming we have **two** pdf looking like these

- 1.pdf: http://ge.tt/1tl71Gf/v/0
- 2.pdf: http://ge.tt/1tl71Gf/v/1

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

we want to join these two pdf pages into new ***single one*** page loking like this, in order to waste not too much paper and economize (see the following left image:
http://ge.tt/1tl71Gf/v/3), instead to having a lot of white space between the text of two pages (see the following right image: http://ge.tt/1tl71Gf/v/5):

[image: seamless_imposed]
[image: normally joined]

we then start roughly estimating the space left free, in first pdf page, after text, to insert the second page3 with its text. In our case, we have an A4 document, whose sizes, in postscript point, are: **595x841**

in both two pdf pages, we assume that the the text starts more or less at same height, or  in other words, at same distance from upper margin, so, if we want impose the **second** pdf page, with its text, on **first** pdf page, without cover the text of first page, but placing it after this, we need to conveniently **move down** the text content of **second** pdf page

in our sample case I moved down the text content of second pdf page with the help of **pdftk** and **sed**, by 200 points ***(we add the value of down moving to the original height - 841 in our case - to preserve the geometry of page, so 841 becomes 1041, while the height of page remains the same)***

```
sed 's/MediaBox \[0 0 595 841]/MediaBox \[0 200 595 1041 ]/g'<2.pdf>2bis.pdf
```

and the result was this (image in left corner), while originally the text content of second pdf page started as in image in right corner:

[image: moved down]
[image: 2]

now, after done this; we need to over impose the second pdf page on the first pdf page

this can be done, once again, with pdftk, placing the second pdf page with its text moved down, in backround

```
pdftk 1.pdf background 2bis.pdf output seamless_imposed.pdf
```

and this is the result: http://ge.tt/1tl71Gf/v/3

[image: seamless_imposed]

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible. You can merge the pages but not the content.
You would have to extract the content of the first and append the content of the second to the first. Not solved are headers and footers.

Comment: Why did you have to preface this response with it not being possible then offer a semi-insightful answer? Also, it is very possible, but just a question of how much effort you want to put into it.

Comment: In the end its not an automatable process and will always have its drawbacks.

Comment: Again, I must disagree... if anything, the answer given by Dingo is a good start in automating this. I don't see how you can deem this relatively simple task to be "not possible" when IBM can program Watson to beat humans at Jeopardy.

Comment: I agree that this simple example is possible, where page 2 fits exactly the white space on page 1. How often is this happening? I think Dingos assumption is too simple. But what if page 2 is longer. Where are you doing the cut. What about page numbers in the footer? Are you renumbering? Automated? Imagine a document with more than 2 simple pages. Or what if page 2 has a header? Do you can programmatically detect header and footer? What about indices or toc in document? Can you rewrite them?

Answer (score 0):

The tool we use in these cases is
[PdfArranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger)

[image: not cropped]

In the previous example we have several shipping labels wasting half of the page with white spaces at the bottom.

[image: cropped]

Once we've cropped 50% of the bottom individually or in batch by multi-selecting, we save as a merged PDF.

[image: Printer and page settings]
Then when printing, select "print as pdf" and at the page setup settings select 2 pages per side and tweak zoom, fit and page orientation to match your requirements.

[image: ready to print]

In our example we are saving one page per two labels by cropping and combining with PdfArranger and printing settings, certainly there are several tools to achieve the same but this one is pretty light and easy to use.