# pdfjam: Merging multiple pdfs into one page without white space

Tags: pdflatex, pdfjam

which I want to get AB closer without space:

```
------       ------            ----------     ------------
|     |      |      |          |  ————  |    | ——    ——  |
|  A  |      |  B   |          |  |A|B| |    | |A|   |B| |
|     |      |      |          |  ————  |    |  ——   ——  |
|     |      |      |  --->    |        |NOT |           |
|     |      |      |          |        |    |           |
|     |      |      |          |        |    |           |
|     |      |      |          |        |    |           |
------       ------            ------      --------
```

which I use:

```
pdfjam figurea.pdf figureb.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile figureout.pdf
```

Comment: |AB| Not like |A   B|

Comment: What does `pdfjam --help` provide in terms of the default settings? There is a `delta` option - [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) that specifies the space between logical pages (both x and y).

Comment: Related/duplicate (cross-network): [How to merge multiple PDF files onto one page with pdftk?](https://superuser.com/q/366490/100579)

Comment: delta not work，the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260020/merge-two-pdf-pages-into-new-one-without-blank-spaces-between-text-content

Comment: I recently had a similar problem. The difference was that the pages I needed to merge had different dimensions. I tried using `pdfjam`, but I had trouble aligning the pages. I posted a workaround based on LaTeX in the following post: ["How to join multiple PDF pages to a single Page"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71802078/16109419).

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying a negative value for `delta`:

```
pdfjam figurea.pdf figureb.pdf --delta '-10 0' --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile figureout.pdf
```